# VBA column selection for range based on data in same row

Tags: excel, vba

In VBA how do I identify a column start location in a paste range based on the value in a cell in another column on the same row?

Answer (score -1):

Sorry i didnt really understand what you want to do, My macro will paste your copied cells when it find value in RngB, to use the macro you will need to copy something and then execute the macro.

```
Sub AKsooner()
Dim RngA As Range, RngB As Range
Dim Cel As Range
' You can change RngA and RngB to the columns you like
Set RngA = ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
Set RngB = ActiveSheet.Columns("B")

' also this if condition is for copy only u can add "or xlcut" to it too
If Application.CutCopyMode = xlCopy Then
   For Each Cel In RngB.Cells
       If Not Cel.Value = 0 Then
          Cells(Cel.Row, RngA.Column).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
          Exit For
       End If
   Next Cel
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Mina Saad, I am looking to shift the column for the paste function only as the spreadsheet I am copying from will always be the same format, but the one I am pasting into moves one column over to the right once a month.